Why am I getting no proper response text returned when web scraping this site?
Basically, I'm trying to scrape a website, but I'm getting no return value in response. Printed response.text and it's not giving the dynamic data. Only the non-dynamic stuff in . Printed response but I'm simply getting <Response [200]>. Anyone know any solution to my problem?Also, when I click disable JS, then enable JS, there are no requests after I refresh the page for some reason in XHR/Fetch in Network despite it being a dynamic website
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Set up the URL
url = "https://www.amazon.jobs/en/search?base_query=&loc_query="

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
    # Find all job titles
    job_titles = soup.find_all('h3', class_='job-title')

    # Print the job titles
    for title in job_titles:
        print(title.text.strip())
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve the page. Status code:", response.status_code)

I tried beautiful soup, scrapy, and simple requests, but nothing is working.

For response.text? @CodeMaven42? - Because print(title.text.strip()) is printing nothing

The page which you are trying to scrape includes lots of js and bs4 only reads static content so try using, selenium

The data is loaded dynamically so you need to check the network tab and reverse engineer the request made. There's a link that goes to a page starting with this url https://www.amazon.jobs/en/search.json?radius=24km&... Use that and you will get a json response back that you can parse.

Hmm. That's weird. For some reason, when I disable and enable JS for other sites, no response request is appearing in xhr/fetch too

We can extract the data from the background request.
API URL: https://www.amazon.jobs/en/search.json?radius=24km&facets%5B%5D=normalized_country_code&facets%5B%5D=normalized_state_name&facets%5B%5D=normalized_city_name&facets%5B%5D=location&facets%5B%5D=business_category&facets%5B%5D=category&facets%5B%5D=schedule_type_id&facets%5B%5D=employee_class&facets%5B%5D=normalized_location&facets%5B%5D=job_function_id&facets%5B%5D=is_manager&facets%5B%5D=is_intern&offset=0&result_limit=100&sort=relevant&latitude=&longitude=&loc_group_id=&loc_query=&base_query=&city=&country=&region=&county=&query_options=&
import requests
import json


# Set up the URL
url = "https://www.amazon.jobs/en/search.json?radius=24km&facets%5B%5D=normalized_country_code&facets%5B%5D=normalized_state_name&facets%5B%5D=normalized_city_name&facets%5B%5D=location&facets%5B%5D=business_category&facets%5B%5D=category&facets%5B%5D=schedule_type_id&facets%5B%5D=employee_class&facets%5B%5D=normalized_location&facets%5B%5D=job_function_id&facets%5B%5D=is_manager&facets%5B%5D=is_intern&offset=0&result_limit=100&sort=relevant&latitude=&longitude=&loc_group_id=&loc_query=&base_query=&city=&country=&region=&county=&query_options=&"

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the JSON content
    data = response.json()
    
    # Find all job titles
    jobs_list = data['jobs']

    # Print the job titles
    for job in jobs_list:
        print(job['title'].strip())
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve the page. Status code:", response.status_code)

